# Using FOP to generate french PDF document, can't resolve 'œ' character

Tags: xml, pdf-generation, apache-fop

I am using  iso-8859-15 encoding both in xml data and in the xslt style sheet.  But when I try convert XML doc to FO document 'œ' does'nt show up it shows up as '?'  Below is the example of the problem I am facing.

The xml data is as follows:
Nous sommes sous l'emprise du Divin cœur de Celui que mon fils vénère par-dessus

in the fo file the same line is generated as :

```
<fo:inline color="#FFFFFF">--------</fo:inline>Nous sommes sous l'emprise du Divin c?ur de Celui que mon fils vénère par-dessus </fo:block>
```

As you see all the other accents are getting generated fine except for the 'œ'character.

Any help is greatly appreciated. This one issue is holding up a project.

Comment: The other accents are all present in ISO-8859-1. The œ is the exception, and only present in ISO-8859-15. As a test, try adding €. That is also a valid 8859-15 character, but not in 8859-1.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/faq.html#pdf-characters ? It could be that you're simply using a font that doesn't have that character. See also http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/stable/fonts.html on how to configure fonts.

However, given that you get a '?' and not a '#' for the missing character could indicate that there's an encoding problem. Sun JVMs usually replace characters that are not in an encoding by a '?'. You might want to consider switching to UTF-8 even though ISO 8859-15 should support the characters you want to use. Since I don't have access to your XML file here, I can't figure out if there's something wrong with it.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the input, I will try to check the font and also I will try with utf-8. Your help is appreciated.